# Given an image of an object with a known size taken from a tilted camera at a known angle, how can I calculate the distance to that object?

Tags: trigonometry, computer-vision

I am working on a small project wherein I am estimating the distance to an object of a known size, both physical and pixel dimensions.

So far I have used a triangle similarity approach and I have measured the distance down to a few millimeters in deviation from the actual distance. With that approach, I calculated a focal length of my camera using the specific pixel height of the object at a known distance. However, that was before I tilted the camera.

What approach can I take now that the camera is tilted?

Comment: Do you know the angle of the object relative to the camera’s line of sight?

Comment: Yes that angle is known.